# Custom Directive is not working in Angular 16

Tags: html, angular, angular-directive, directive

[image: My Html input line directive 'Directive name datePickerDir']

[image: app.module.ts]

[image: date-picker.directive.ts]

I have tried all of the way, but i missed something i think.

I want a result of calling the directice on load for my new datepicker field.
I am doing this for a custom date picker field.

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, AfterViewInit, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[datePickerDir]',
})

export class DatePickerDirective implements OnInit {

    constructor() {
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        console.log('This is not triggering on load');
    }
}
```

TIA.

Comment: See that you need include the directive in the `declarations` array of the **module** where your component is also declared (that can be not the AppModule): if your component is declared in ComponentsModule, is in this module where you declared the directive. NOTE: Please, not post images, better add in your question as code (select all the code and use Ctrl+K)

Comment: it's  better to get stackliz code link to give you absolute solution.